# Collection view cell causes breakpoint crash

Tags: uicollectionview, breakpoints

Within my collection view, when the cell is clicked to show the detailed view controller via a push segue, it crashes - apparently because of a breakpoint with a property connecting to an imageview.

The code is as follows - that's causing the problem.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController   
@property  (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;              // <--- break point.     
@end
```

The segue identifiers are correct etc.

I started a similar thread but this post is more specific.

Comment: Instead of creating a new question about the same issue, but with more detail, you should update your previous question and delete this one.

Comment: That's useful, and not confusing at all.